# How to use findViewById variable in another method. Java Android

Tags: java, android, variables, switch-statement, findviewbyid

I am very new to programming and am teaching myself so sorry if my code is ugly.

I am trying to create a menu like screen that has left and right arrow buttons that change the picture displayed.  I want to make it so when your on the first image the left arrow is gone and when on the last image is displayed the right arrow is gone.

I have tried to do this a lot of different ways but always end up needing a variable somewhere where it cannot be resolved.  In the code posted the error is in the switch statement and I other ways I have tried to code it the unresolved variable error would be in the onClickListener.

You don't have to code it for me, just let me know what concept I am missing and I will study up on it.

Thanks

```
    package com.mystuff.mymenu;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;



public class PictureMenu extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

int setView = 1;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.picture_menu);  

    menuSet(setView);

ImageButton right = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rightButton);
ImageButton left = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.leftButton);
right.setOnClickListener(this);
left.setOnClickListener(this);

}       
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if(v.getId() == R.id.rightButton){
    setView ++;
    menuSet(setView);
if(v.getId() == R.id.rightButton){
    setView ++;
        menuSet(setView);
}
    }   
    }


private void menuSet(int setView) {

    ImageView picture1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture1);
    ImageView picture2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture2);
    ImageView picture3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture3);
    ImageView picture4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture4);

    switch(setView){
    case 1: 
        left.setVisibility(View.GONE);  //ERROR left cannot be resolved
        right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //ERROR right cannot be resolved
        picture1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        picture2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case 2:
        left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //ERROR left cannot be resolved
        right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //ERROR right cannot be resolved
        picture1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        picture3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case 3: 
        left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //ERROR left cannot be resolved
        right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //ERROR right cannot be resolved
        picture1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        picture4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case 4: 
        left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //ERROR left cannot be resolved
        right.setVisibility(View.GONE); //ERROR right cannot be resolved
        picture1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    default:
        left.setVisibility(View.GONE);  //ERROR left cannot be resolved
        right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //ERROR right cannot be resolved
        picture1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        picture2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
}       


}



}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your problem lies in that *right* and *left* are local to *onCreate()* method, and cannot be seen from outside that method. If you want them class-scope, make them class attributes, e.g.:

```
public class PictureMenu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    int setView = 1; 
    ImageButton right, left;
    ...

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        right = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rightButton);
        left = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.leftButton);
        ...
    }
```

Another solution would be passing them as arguments to *menuSet()*

IMHO, you should first learn proper programming, specially what [variable scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_scope) is.
Also properly formatting your code helps easily spotting scopes.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
    package com.mystuff.mymenu;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;



public class PictureMenu extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private ImageButton right, left; 

int setView = 1;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.picture_menu);  

    menuSet(setView);

right = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rightButton);
left = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.leftButton);
right.setOnClickListener(this);
left.setOnClickListener(this);

}       
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if(v.getId() == R.id.rightButton){
    setView ++;
    menuSet(setView);
if(v.getId() == R.id.rightButton){
    setView ++;
        menuSet(setView);
}
    }   
    }


private void menuSet(int setView) {

    switch(setView){
    case 1: 
        left.setVisibility(View.GONE);  //ERROR left cannot be resolved
        right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //ERROR right cannot be resolved
        picture1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        picture2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case 2:
        left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //ERROR left cannot be resolved
        right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //ERROR right cannot be resolved
        picture1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        picture3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case 3: 
        left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //ERROR left cannot be resolved
        right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //ERROR right cannot be resolved
        picture1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        picture4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case 4: 
        left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //ERROR left cannot be resolved
        right.setVisibility(View.GONE); //ERROR right cannot be resolved
        picture1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    default:
        left.setVisibility(View.GONE);  //ERROR left cannot be resolved
        right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //ERROR right cannot be resolved
        picture1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        picture2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        picture4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
}       


}



}
```